# How do I get the number of posts on each day with annotation in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, annotate

I have a `Post` model that has a `datetime.date` field for `posted_date`. I need to find how many posts are made by a user on each day. Creating a query for each day seems silly.

I couldn't figure out how to make the aggregation API query using annotate.

Is

```
Post.objects.filter(author=someuser).annotate(dailycount=Count('posted_day'))
```

the correct way? Then, how do I use this to get number of posts for a particular day?

My model is:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    posted_day=models.DateField(default=date.today)
    author=models.ForeignKey(User,null=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. You need two additional clauses:

```
day_counts = Post.objects.filter(author=someuser).values('posted_day').annotate(
                                       dailycount=Count('posted_day')).order_by()
```

The `values('posted_day')` enables the grouping, and the empty `order_by` ensures the results are ordered by `posted_day` so the default ordering doesn't interfere.

The clearest documentation of this seems to be in the [Django Aggregation docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregation) section on the [Order of `annotate()` and `values()` clauses](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-values-clauses).

`values` returns a `list` of `dicts` like:

```
[{'posted-day': 'the-first-day', 'dailycount': 2}, . . . ,
 {'posted-day': 'the-last-day', 'dailycount': 3}]
```

so if you wanted the last day the user posted, it would be the last item in the list:

```
last_day_dict = day_counts[-1]
date = last_day_dict['posted_day']
count = last_day_dict['dailycount']
```

You can then compare `date` to `today()` to see if they match, and if they don't the user didn't post today, and if he did, he posted `count` times.

Comment: thanks for the reply..from the returned queryset ,how do I find the number of posts on `day1` which is  say `datetime.date.today()` ?

Comment: @damon I added more info to my answer.